# Create SEO-friendly URL with PHP with just the Querystring Value

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Is there a way use mod_rewrite to produce the result below?

Original URL:
**http://www.domain.com/shop.php?id=newyork**

to

SEO friendly URL
**http://www.domain.com/newyork**

I've seen plenty of example where the above URL can be converted to **http://www.domain.com/shop/newyork** but I actually don't want to display the word '**shop/**' so just **http://www.domain.com/newyork**

Comment: Note: if you want URLs like this you cannot differentiate other kind of urls like restaurant.php?id=newyork so your apparoach is working only when you want to display shops only.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a go with something like the following, off the top of my head

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)$ www.example.com/shop.php?id=$1
```

Do bear in mind that anything after your root domain, will be piped into your shop.php script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your .htaccess file put

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/([^/.]+)$ shop.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`([^/.]+)` will match anything that isn't a `/` or `.` and store that info,
`$1` at the end outputs that info into your shop script.
`[L]` tells mod_rewrite to stop looking for rules if this one works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /shop.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Would match `newyork`, `alaska`, `hamburg` but not `highway-1`.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly because the http://www.domain.com/ and http://www.domain.com/about.php do not redirect to http://www.domain.com/shop.php?.  Because I have the list of all the pages other than shop, I'm thinking to write it out like this RewriteRule ^(about)$ /about.php RewriteRule ^(contact)$ /contact.php RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /page.php?id=$1. Is this the right way to do this? To detect first for any of the pages before calling the 'shop' rewrite.

Comment: Yes, I think this could work. The only problem I see is this rule `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /page.php?id=$1` because it is, more or less the same as `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /shop.php?id=$1 [L]`

I would asume the your `shop` rule will never be called, because it will be matched first by your `page` rule.

And make sure you add the `[L]`, which stands for last rule, after each `RewriteRule`.